# Formula help: assign points to "yes" and "no" and find sum for column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have the following in a worksheet:

```
Daily login
------------
yes
no
yes
yes
no
```

For every YES I need a score of 5, and for every NO I need a score of -3.

I need to find the sum of all YES and NO in the column. e.g., in the above case, the total is 9 (3 x 5 = 15 for the YESs, plus 2 x -3 = -6 for the NOs). How can I do this with a formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `IF` function you can get the result for the cells as, (starting from `B1`

```
=IF(A1="yes", 5, IF(A1="no", -3, 0))
```

After that using `SUM`, you can get the expected result as, (placed at `C1`)

```
=SUM(B1:B5)
```

Screenshot:

> [image: Excel]

Answer (score 0):

Use two Countif():

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"Yes")*5 + COUNTIF(A:A,"No")*-3
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Can you also tell me how can I add this formula within =IF((M34/5)+(N34/2.5)+F12+F22+F32+F42<100,(M34/5)+(N34/2.5)+F12+F22+F32+F42,"BRONE III ACHIEVED"). And if you can suggest a simpler formula that I did not know of.

Comment: New questions get new posts.  If this answered your question please mark it as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.